# A value stored in an object dumbed in the outer scope of a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope

I have the following function:

```js
function exec(command) {
    const stdout = {
        command: null,
        output: null
    };
    stdout.command = command;
    chproc.exec(command, (error, out, stderr) => {
        if (error || stderr) {
            console.error(error || stderr);
            return;
        }
        temp = out;
    });
    stdout.output = temp;
    return stdout;
```

where `const chproc = require('child_process');` , I've been trying to store the output in the callback function in `chproc.exec` in the object `stdout`, but it does so only within the scope of the callback function not the outer `exec` function which goes back to null. The thing is, this works, if `stdout` is in global scope and I am writing each code line in the Node.js terminal -if I run the file, this too doesn't work for some reason-, so as you see, I am in a confusing mess, if anyone can help clear it up, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

chproc.exec accepts command and a callback , which gets called when exec completes its call. So if you are wrapping it in your own function , then I suggest you keep the same function signature.

```
function exec(command, callback) {
    const stdout = {
        command: null,
        output: null
    };
    stdout.command = command;
    let temp;
    chproc.exec(command, (error, out, stderr) => {
        if (error || stderr) {
            console.error(error || stderr);
            return;
        }
        callback(out);
    });
    return stdout;
}

exec('ls', function (output) {
    console.log(output);
});
```